# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5df1170a921ee283d8529aa3'

Tags: python, angular, api

I am trying to retrieve one book from a json of books. When retrieving a single book i get this Value Error message on the line that is in bold.
Error -
show_all_books
    page_num = int(request.args.get('pn'))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5df1170a921ee283d8529aa3'

```
@app.route("/api/v1.0/books", methods=["GET"])
def show_all_books():
   page_num, page_size = 1, 10
if request.args.get('pn'):
    ***page_num = int(request.args.get('pn'))***
if request.args.get('ps'):
    page_size = int(request.args.get('ps'))
page_start = (page_size * (page_num - 1))
```

Comment: What is it that you don't understand ? of course  "5df1170a921ee283d8529aa3" is not a valid value for `int()`. Rule N°1: __never__ trust unsanitized user data.

Comment: Sorry new to this all, what would you suggest changing on the code above?

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because you can't convert the string to integer because it have characters that doesn't allow it:

```
int('5df1170a921ee283d8529aa3')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5df1170a921ee283d8529aa3'
```

If you try with a number:

```
int('1231')
1231
```

So I think that the problem is with the data you receive in `get('pn')`. The default base of the int() function is 10 but you can do this with hexadecimal base:

```
int('5df1170a921ee283d8529aa3', 16)
29073565845337865796180941475L
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because the string passed to the function can not be represented as an integer.
For instance if you were to do:

```
int('abc')
```

you'd get the same error, because the string abc can not be represented as an integer.